# How we substract two column and store in another column in laravel,i am new in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have 3 columns in database:

- First column `Fee`
- Second column `First_installement`
- Third column `second_installement`
- Fourth column `third_installement`
- Fourth column `dues`

I want

```
dues=fee-(first_installement+second_installement+third_installement)
```

My controller

```
$patientfee=AddPatient::find($patient_id);
$a->fee_id=$request->input('fee_id');
$b->first_installement=$request->input('first_installement');
$c->second_installement=$request->input('second_installement');
$d->third_installement=$request->input('third_installement');
$e->dues=$request->input('dues');

$e=$a-($b+$c+$d);

$patientfee->update();
return redirect('/patient-list')->with('status','Fee Successfully  updated');
```

Comment: HI you can do like that 

SELECT `p_Id`,`user_id`,`doc_id`,`credit` ,`app_date`,`expires_on`,
       (credit -debited_amount) AS credit
FROM `wp_loyalty_credits`
WHERE `expires_on`>now() and (credit > debited_amount or debited_amount is null);

and for update coloum just update the new  value

Comment: where you want substract ? when you save or ? when you show in view page ?

Comment: Which all columns do you want to subtract?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that like first retrieve column values from `AddPatient` and then subtract.

```
$patientfee=AddPatient::findOrFail($patient_id);
$fee = $patientfee->fee;
$first_installement = $patientfee->first_installement;
$second_installement = $patientfee->second_installement;
$third_installement = $patientfee->third_installement;

$dues = $fee - ($first_installement+$second_installement+$third_installement);
$patientfee->dues = $dues;
$patientfee->update();
return redirect('/patient-list')->with('status','Fee Successfully  updated');
```